# How to strip html tags and leave link from a variable in php

Tags: php, html, strip-tags

How do I strip the HTML tags from a variable and leave the link? I am trying to send emails with the link but without the tags. I've tried `strip_tags()`, but it removes the link.

`$var = "this is a link <a href="mylink"/>yes it is</a>;`

`$message ="$var"; // email massage`

How would I go about making it into
"this is a link mylink yes it is"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this could help you

```
$message = strip_tags(preg_replace('/<a href="(.*)">/', '$1', $var));
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, Flask.  But this is still stripping away the link. I tried to modify it but no luck. Have any idea why shit could be happening?

Comment: hey holidaymaine. maybe because your link is not valid? its self closing.. <a href="mylink"/> guess the / at the end is missplaced?

Comment: You were right Flask. The link was not valid. Thank you this worked great.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression to remove just tags, but not the link itself, if strip_tags does not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
$regex  = '/<\/?[a-zA-Z0-9=\s\"\._]+>/';
preg_replace($regex,'',$mystring);
```

this will remove tags but leave it's contents. I'm not sure I've included all the necessary chars. you can add them later =)

Comment: Thank you, Headshota. Your code is not stripping away anything. I tried a combination of your answer and Flask's answer, but no luck.

Comment: Your code is still not stripping anything even after I validated the link as Flask suggested.